# What is the multiarch support for Google Earth 64 bit package?

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, multiarch

The [official Ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth#Installing_the_.deb_file_downloaded_from_the_Google_Earth_Website) for Google Earth says this:

> Note to 64bit users: The 64bit debian package depends on ia32-libs
>   which is deprecated and no longer available as of 13.10 Saucy. Use the
>   32bit package and multiarch-support.

Where is this multiarch-support and how can I ensure it is installed?

This is for a re-installation of the 64-bit version. The Software Updater lists http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/stable main under the 'Other Software' tab. Does that mean multiarch-support is set to update as part of that?

(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Nvidia GeForce 430 using Nvidia binary driver v. 331.113)

Comment: The above 'duplicate' has the steps to 'enable' multi-arch.  However, it should already be enabled in 14.04...

Comment: @ThomasW.  Alright then i'll discard that as the installation issue. I guess i'll click on 'That solved my problem!', as although it didn't, it answers the question.  I'd personally say that should be changed to 'That answered my question'.  I have started trying to break problems I ask about down into chunks to keep them more relevant to other users - if i can, as my knowledge is basic.  At any rate so far when i come here asking it often takes me 2 or more questions before it is sorted out.

Comment: lets keep in mind that your question would have the same answer - multiarch support needs no 'installation' but it needs an additional configuration step.  From there, 32bit packages can be installed, which in turn solves the issue of 'No Multi Arch'

Comment: @ThomasW. It isn't that it wasn't helpful. It just didn't solve my problem and it wasn't meant to. Ask is littered with answers that are outdated or so specific to one system that they aren't useful to anyone else.  (The 2nd issue is due to people like me.) It doesn't seem like a good idea to encourage people in any way to think that the two possibilities are 'this isn't a dupe' (edit) or, 'That solved my problem!'. The main issue is that *I don't know Ubuntu* and I'm trying to solve that as much as the particular problem now. I wish Ask was a guide to *that* - learning, not troubleshooting.